# Pspice to Simulink/Matlab

Tags: matlab, pspice

I made a circuit in Orcad Capture and I want to co-simulate it in Simulink, for other future operation, and a problem appeared: I can't connect my PSpice Block to a VDC source from Simulink (see picture.), although I made the next settings for PSpice block (see second picture.), where V10 is a VDC source (5V).
I made some research and I saw that a 'Solver configuration' is necessary at a point and all components must be from the same Library (but my block is not in the default library of Simulink).

[image]
[image]

Comment: You seem to be using some type of circuit simulation toolbox that isn't compatible with your pspice block.

Comment: Yes, because I don't know from where to get the right components. All VDC sources that I tried none of it was good.

Comment: Judging by the fact that the input to the pspice block is a standard simulink ">" input, I would think you need to provide it a regular old simulink signal. I would guess feeding it a 1 would indicate 1 volt above ground, but you'll have to read the manuals to know for sure.

Comment: In Orcad the V10 VDC source have the value of 5V, but I will try what you said.

Comment: I expect the input note's value in the SPICE netlist is completely ignored in favor of whatever input you feed it.

Comment: It worked, Thank you!